# Scrollview not scroll inside linearlayout android

Tags: android, scroll

Following is the code of layout xml that i have tried to implement, i don't know what is the issue behind it  Can anyone help me?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/activity_post"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/white"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="1">
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.95"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/value_3"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/search_text"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
                android:id="@+id/imgChat"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_30">
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/msgCount"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20" />
                <ImageView
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMsg"
                    android:src="@drawable/chatt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--<LinearLayout />-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@color/rv_color"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:id="@+id/rvHairList"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:clipToPadding="false" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:indeterminateTint="@color/user_name"
                        android:id="@+id/main_progress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                    <include
                        layout="@layout/error_layout"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
    android:padding="@dimen/value_5"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDrawer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:src="@drawable/more"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llHome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHome"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:src="@drawable/home"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgFriendRequest"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/friendCount"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/imgFnd"
            android:src="@drawable/add_friend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gestureImg"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:src="@drawable/img_thing"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llNewPost"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGallery"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgNotification"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/notiCount"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/imgNoti"
            android:src="@drawable/notification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProfile"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/imgTimeline"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:src="@drawable/loader"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

scrollview not scrolling
i have tried to change height of scrollview and linearlayout of scrollview but not get any solution

Comment: use nested scrollview

Comment: i have tried it but no change found

Comment: @JaydeepPatel nested scroll not scrolling recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Set 0dp instead of wrap_content in android:layout_height="wrap_content"

```
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.95"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have manage the `weight` of `ScrollView` and `Layout's` and fix
>   the bottom LinearLayout height  like Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"> 

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/value_3"
                    android:text="@string/search_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
                    tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imgChat"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/value_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_5"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
                    tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/msgCount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/round"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgMsg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/chatt"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--<LinearLayout />-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/rv_color"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/rvHairList"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:clipToPadding="false"
                                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/main_progress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:indeterminateTint="@color/user_name" />

                        <include layout="@layout/error_layout" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/value_5"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDrawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
                android:src="@drawable/more"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgHome"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgFriendRequest"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_friend"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gestureImg"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
                android:src="@drawable/img_thing"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llNewPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgGallery"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
                android:src="@drawable/gallery"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgNotification"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notiCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNoti"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/notification"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
                android:id="@+id/imgTimeline"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_20"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/loader"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think there is problem with weight value and tools:ignore="NestedWeights" statement, you have to manage it with without weight and NestedWeights statement.

Comment: how can it's posible give suggetion

Comment: give me some time, i will update my answer with working code.